# Comparing float and double

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    float a = 1.1;
    double b = 1.1;
    if(a == b){
        printf("if block");
    }
    else{
        printf("else block");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Prints: else block

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    float a = 1.5;
    double b = 1.5;
    if(a == b){
        printf("if block");
    }
    else{
        printf("else block");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Prints: if block

What is the logic behind this?

Compiler used: gcc-4.3.4

Comment: Try turning on `-Wfloat-equal` in your compiler. It's a useful warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `1.1` is not exactly representable in binary floating-point. But `1.5` is.

As a result, the `float` and `double` representations will hold slightly different values of `1.1`.

Here is exactly the difference when written out as binary floating-point:

```
(float) 1.1 = (0.00011001100110011001101)₂
(double)1.1 = (0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010)₂
```

Thus, when you compare them (and the `float` version gets promoted), they will not be equal.

Comment: The first 0 ought to be 1; it is just implicit in the floating point representation :D

Answer (score 4):

Must read: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1):

The exact value of 1.1 decimal in binary is non-ending fraction 1.00011001100110011001100(1100).... The double constant `1.1` is 53-bit truncation / approximate value of that *mantissa*. Now this when converted to float, the mantissa will be represented just in *24* bits.

When the `float` is converted back to double, the mantissa is now back to 53 bits, but all memory of the digits beyond 24 are lost - the value is zero-extended, and now you're comparing (for example, depending on the rounding behaviour)

```
1.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001
```

and

```
1.0001100110011001100110000000000000000000000000000000
```

**Now, if you used 1.5 instead of 1.1;**

1.5 decimal is exactly **1.1 in binary**. It can be presented exactly in just **2** bit mantissa, therefore even the 24 bits of float are an exaggeration... what you have is

```
1.1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

and

```
1.10000000000000000000000
```

The latter, zero extended to a double would be

```
1.1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

which clearly is the same number.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info :)