# float vs double comparison

Tags: c

```
int main(void)
{
    float me = 1.1;       
    double you = 1.1;   

    if ( me == you ) {
        printf("I love U");
    } else {
        printf("I hate U");
    }
}
```

This prints "I hate U". Why?

Comment: `1.1` is by default `double`, converted to `float` when used to initialize `me`. Before `me` is compared with `you`, `me` is converted back to `double`. If the first conversion is lossy, you get a `FALSE` when compared equal. Down vote for notation of `me` `U` which makes the question uncomfortable to write an answer to.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Next time you provide proper formatting and a correct question. In other words a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the compiler hates you...

Comment: @user3528438: just let the kids use their own language. For an answer, you can use yours. If he cannot transpose, it is his problem actually. (However, he has a point: use more neutral terms).

Comment: What sites have you searched on?  Links?

Comment: Did you even try to look for an existing answer to this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343155/double-and-float-comparison  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014303/comparing-float-and-double  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722293/why-comparing-double-and-float-leads-to-unexpected-result

Answer (score 3):

Floats use binary fraction. If you convert `1.1` to float, this will result in a binary representation.
Each bit right if the binary point halves the weight of the digit, as much as for decimal, it divides by ten. Bits left of the point double (times ten for decimal).

```
in decimal: ... 0*2 + 1*1 + 0*0.5 + 0*0.25 + 0*0.125 + 1*0.0625 + ...
binary:          0    1  .  0       0        0         1          ...
2's exp:         1    0    -1      -2       -3        -4
(exponent to the power of 2)
```

Problem is that `1.1` cannot be converted exactly to binary representation. For double, there are, however, more significant digits than for float.

If you compare the values, first, the float is converted to double. But as the computer does not know about the original decimal value, it simply fills the trailing digits of the new double with all `0`, while the double value is more precise. So both do compare not equal.

This is a common pitfall when using floats. For this and other reasons (e.g. rounding errors), you should not use exact comparison for equal/unequal), but a ranged compare using the smallest value different from 0:

```
#include "float.h"

...
// check for "almost equal"
if ( fabs(fval - dval) <= FLT_EPSILON )
    ...
```

Note the usage of FLT_EPSILON, which is the aforementioned value for single precision `float` values. Also note the `<=`, not `<`, as the latter will actually require exact match).

If you compare two doubles, you might use DBL_EPSILON, but be careful with that.

Depending on intermediate calculations, the tolerance has to be increased (you cannot reduce it further than epsilon), as rounding errors, etc. will sum up. Floats in general are not forgiving with wrong assumptions about precision, conversion and rounding.

**Edit:**

As suggested by @chux, this might not work as expected for larger values, as you have to scale EPSILON according to the exponents. This conforms to what I stated: float comparision is not that simple as integer comparison. Think about before comparing.

Comment: With FP math, suggest `fabs()` rather than `abs()`.

Comment: FP numbers are logarithmically distributed.  Using `abs(fval - dval) <= FLT_EPSILON/DBL_EPSILON` is a bad idea.  For large values, the code is effectively `if (fval == dval)`.  For small values, the code is effectively `if (true)`. A good _nearness_ comparison involves looking at the ratio of the 2 numbers with special handing for different signs and 0.

Comment: @chux: You have a point. I added a comment to my answer. Thanks. I just do not use float in my every-day work (luckily).

Answer (score 1):

In short, you should NOT use `==` to compare floating points.

for example

`float i = 1.1;` // or double

`float j = 1.1;` // or double

This argument
 `(i==j) == true` // is not always valid

for a correct comparison you should use epsilon (very small number):

`(abs(i-j)<epsilon)== true` // this argument is valid

Comment: Why adding? I already mentioned that.

Comment: With `int abs(int j);`, code is doing an integer absolute value.  Suggest `fabs()`.

Comment: `(abs(i-j)<epsilon)` is a poor idea.  Consider `i = 1e-20; j = 2e-20`.  They differ by 100%, but appear to be the same with `(abs(i-j)<epsilon)`.

Comment: @chux if you make epsilon to be < 1e-21 then i and j are different and my argument is still valid....

Comment: @Samer Your suggestion to alter `epsilon` because  `i,j` is small is exactly the point: `epsilon` as a constant does not work well.  The value compared to `|i-j|` needs to vary depending on `i,j`.  [R..](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10335601/2410359) answers this well.

Answer (score 1):

The question simplifies to why do `me` and `you` have different values?

*Usually*, C floating point is based on a binary representation.  Many compilers & hardware follow IEEE 754 [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) and [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).  Rare machines use a decimal, base-16 or other floating point representation.

OP's machine certainly does not represent 1.1 exactly as 1.1, but to the nearest representable floating point number.

Consider the below which prints out `me` and `you` to high precision.  The previous representable floating point numbers are also shown.  It is easy to see `me != you`.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    float me = 1.1;
    double you = 1.1;
    printf("%.50f\n", nextafterf(me,0)); // previous float value
    printf("%.50f\n", me);
    printf("%.50f\n", nextafter(you,0)); // previous double value
    printf("%.50f\n", you);

1.09999990463256835937500000000000000000000000000000
1.10000002384185791015625000000000000000000000000000
1.09999999999999986677323704498121514916420000000000
1.10000000000000008881784197001252323389053300000000
```

---

But it is more complicated:  C allows code to use higher precision for intermediate calculations depending on `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.  So on another machine, where `FLT_EVAL_METHOD==1` (evaluate all FP to `double`), the compare test may pass.

Comparing for exact equality is rarely used in floating point code, aside from comparison to 0.0.  More often code uses an ordered compare `a < b`.  Comparing for approximate equality involves another parameter to control *how near*.  [@R..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335601/2410359) has a good answer on that.

Comment: Where are the `nextafter` functions declared?

Comment: @Olaf `nextafter()` declared in `<math.h>` (C99).

Answer (score 0):

Because you are comparing two **Floating point!**

Floating point comparison is not exact because of [Rounding Errors](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/rounding/). Simple values like 1.1 or 9.0 cannot be precisely represented using binary floating point numbers, and the limited precision of floating point numbers means that slight changes in the order of operations can change the result. Different compilers and CPU architectures store temporary results at different precisions, so results will differ depending on the details of your environment. For example:

```
float a = 9.0 + 16.0
double b = 25.0
if(a == b) // can be false!
if(a >= b) // can also be false!
```

Even

```
if(abs(a-b) < 0.0001) // wrong - don't do this
```

This is a bad way to do it because a fixed epsilon (0.0001) is chosen because it “looks small”, could actually be way too large when the numbers being compared are very small as well.

I personally use the following method, may be this will help you:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <cmath>        // std::abs
#include <algorithm>    // std::min
using namespace std;

#define MIN_NORMAL 1.17549435E-38f
#define MAX_VALUE 3.4028235E38f

bool nearlyEqual(float a, float b, float epsilon) {
    float absA = std::abs(a);
    float absB = std::abs(b);
    float diff = std::abs(a - b);

    if (a == b) {
        return true;
    } else if (a == 0 || b == 0 || diff < MIN_NORMAL) {
        return diff < (epsilon * MIN_NORMAL);
    } else {
        return diff / std::min(absA + absB, MAX_VALUE) < epsilon;
    }
}
```

This method [passes](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/NearlyEqualsTest.java) tests for many important special cases, for different `a`, `b` and `epsilon`.

And don't forget to read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)!

Comment: On the right track with this answer, but it is a `C` question - recommend `C` code.

Comment: BTW: Floating point comparison _is_ exact.   Its `a` and `b` are just not as expected.

Comment: Sidenote: The question is actually not about rounding errors, but decimal-binary conversion and truncation. But, yes, they are all a nasty pack.